# Android INSERT statement problems

Tags: android, database, insert

I am getting syntax error when trying to insert data into my database when it is created.

I am using the following code:

```
//DatabaseHelper class
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_INSPECTION_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_AREA_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_RUN_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOCATION_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_INSPECTORS_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ISSUE_LOCATION_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ISSUE_TYPE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_RACKING_SYSTEM_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_COMPONENT_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_RISK_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ACTION_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_MANUFACTURER_TABLE);

        db.rawQuery("INSERT INTO " + INSPECTORS_TABLE + "(" + INSPECTOR_NAME + ") " + 
                "SELECT 'Joe Bloggs' AS " + INSPECTOR_NAME +
                " UNION SELECT 'John Major' " +
                " UNION SELECT 'Dan the man'"
                , null);

        db.rawQuery("INSERT INTO " + ACTION_TABLE + "(" + ACTION_REQUIRED + ") " + 
                "SELECT 'Red Risk' AS " + ACTION_REQUIRED +
                " UNION SELECT 'Amber Risk' " +
                " UNION SELECT 'Green Risk'"
                , null);
```

Edited again following RedFliter's great advice.  I'm sure the query is now right, but although I don't get any errors no records get inputed into the tables (deleted the database each time using the DDMS).

Am I putting this code in the right place (i.e. onCreate)?

Not sure where I'm going wrong..

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add single quotes around your strings:

```
db.rawQuery("INSERT INTO " + INSPECTIONS_TABLE + " (" + INSPECTOR_NAME + ")          VALUES " + "('Joe Blogs', 'John Smith', 'Franky Hollywood')", null);
```

This approach is subject to SQL injections. You will need to guard against this.

**Update:**

For multiple row inserts, you need to do:

```
db.rawQuery("INSERT INTO " + INSPECTIONS_TABLE + "(" + INSPECTOR_NAME + ") " + "select 'Joe Bloggs' as " + INSPECTOR_NAME + " UNION ALL select 'John Major' UNION ALL select 'Dan the man'", null);
```

Comment: Ok thanks, tried that but then got SQLiteException: 4 values for 1 columns. Think I should have included brackets but still got errors - I have amended the question accordingly..

Comment: Thanks RedFilter, great response - just got home and will give a go.  Will tick ASAP!! Dave

Comment: RedFilter - still have an issue (see edited question). Will definitely give you a thumbs up and tick this - but any idea why it isn't working?  It looks like the code never gets processed..

Comment: Ah ha - found the issue (pretty obvious really), I swapped db.rawQuery for db.execSQL (removing the ',null' bit at the end) and this worked perfectly!!!  Thanks for your responses!

Answer (score -1):

Use like the following you can defenetly insert the date into the database...

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 values.put(POST_ID,"Your ID here");
 values.put(POSTER_ID,"Poster id " );
 values.put(POSTER_NAME, msg.poster_name);
 values.put(POSTER_IMAGE_PATH,msg.poster_image_path==null ||msg.poster_image_path.length()==0?"":msg.poster_image_path);
 values.put(PLAYER_TYPE, msg.player_type);
 values.put(POST_TEXT, msg.post_text);
 db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
 db.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put string values into quotes

```
db.rawQuery("INSERT INTO " + 
        INSPECTIONS_TABLE + "(" + INSPECTOR_NAME + ") 
        VALUES " + "('Joe Blogs', 'John Smith', 'Franky Hollywood')", null);
```